# Setting SQL Relationships For LINQ Queries

Tags: sql, linq, relationships

I have two tables that I'm trying to create a relationship between so I can write nice LINQ queries that don't require join.

```
Widgets
WidgetId
WidgetDescription

Orders
OrderId
WidgetId
OrderDate
```

What I want to be able to do is create a LINQ query that does something similar to:

```
var result = from x in db.Widgets
Where x.Orders.OrderDate == "5/11/2010"
select x;
```

I can't seem to get intellitext to pick up the other database despite creating a relationship in SQL server.  Are there any additional steps I need to take to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it could be done without either adding `OrderDate` to Widgets in your database, or running a join query before querying it.

I would do something like this.

```
var firstQuery = (for w in Widgets
                  join o in Orders
                  on w.WidgetId equals o.WidgetID
                  select new {Widgets = w, OrderDate = o.OrderDate}).Distinct();

var secondQuery = for record in firstQuery
                  where record.OrderDate == "5/11/2010"
                  select record.Widgets;
```

This way you get an `OrderDate` for each Widget record.

Comment: Because the two tables are associated by WidgetId, would adding OrderDate to Widgets be redundant?  I'm looking at examples like this: (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/29/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database.aspx) and feel like everything is the same, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I was breaking it up into two queries to show you what it was doing. But you could do all of it in one join query. You just stated that you wanted to do it without a join, I was showing how you could create a quick Enumerable that would give you the capability of doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
var result = from widgetId in 
                (from order in orderContext.Orders
                    where order.OrderDate == new DateTime(2010, 5, 11)
                    select order.WidgetId)
            from widget in widgetContext.Widgets
            where widget.WidgetId = widgetId
            select widget;
```